# UEFI in asus H110 motherboard not work

Tags: windows, windows-installation, bootable-media

I have created a bootable GPT and UEFI flash drive. but when I connect it to the system a screen appear that the BIOS configuration is not UEFI, it is legacy, but I set the motherboard configuration to UEFI mode. How could I overcome to this problem?

Comment: Can you update the BIOS on this board?  UEFI has been in place for a decade. Is the board very old?

Comment: But last year I upgraded my CPU and I had to update my BIOS to latest version .

Comment: So does the board now support UEFI?

Comment: Yes it does. it support six and seven generations intel CPU. the chipset is H110M-K ASUS corporation

Comment: My hard disk  is GPT and my current Windows is UEFI . but my windows corrupt and I decide to reinstall the Windows

Comment: BIOS and UEFI are not the same things - correct terminology matters - this is UEFI. CSM [Legacy] Mode sometimes has two settings in some motherboards, ensure they're disabled and boot is set to UEFI only within the UEFI firmware, as [CSM Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI#CSM_booting) should never be enabled unless needing to access a legacy OP ROM, and it should be re-disabled once done in the OP ROM, as its sole purpose was to support distros circa <2017 that yet didn't support EFI boot _(Windows has supported EFI boot since Win7 and all distros supported it as of 2017)_

Comment: "I have created a bootable GPT and UEFI flash drive." - Which means it's not bootable under most situations.  A flash drive cannot be both bootable if it uses the GPT schema and the system boots while under UEFI mode. Use Rufus or the Meida Creation Tool to properly create the installation drive.

Comment: @Ramhound - `A flash drive cannot be both bootable if it uses the GPT schema and the system boots while under UEFI mode` are you sure about that? Ventoy uses GPT partition basically so it WILL boot in UEFI mode